# libgit2sharpAPI gitClient.CreatePushAsync method throwing an exception Multiple operations were attempted on same file

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

**Issue description:**

Modified a file with different contents twice and captured in the array of changes of the GITContent Array to prepare the GITCommit object and tried to push through `gitClient.CreatePushAsync` method all the commits. However its throwing an exception:

> Multiple operations were attempted on file within the same request

Only a single operation may be applied to each file within the same commit.\r\nParameter name: `newPush`.

**Goal:**

I would like to capture all the changes made to the same file as part of the same commit and raise only one single PR request for all the changes of the same file rather creating different commit and PR altogether every time the content of the file is changed which is easy for tracking and approval of the PR for final merge.

Any help on the above exception will be helpful

Comment: What did you already try?

Comment: Right, without some code this question is very challenging to understand...